# Django Token Authorization based on IP

Tags: django

I am looking for some help with respect to token based authorization. We have a client server model. The client contacts the server for the first time and gets a token. This token has to then utilized whenever a new message is sent to the server. I don't have any users as such. The messages are triggers from the system.Can someone please suggest on how to proceed?
I came across this link 
   http://www.tomchristie.com/rest-framework-2-docs/api-guide/authentication

but I am confused when it comes to saving it against a user as I have request from a machine as such.

Answer (score 0):

You can have middleware layer where you can check if the request is from certain IP. If so, then you can program to either allow or deny the request to go through. If a request is allowed, then you can authenticate using Django token authentication. Here I assume you are using something like DRF, Tastypie

```
class MiddleWare2CheckIP(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        ip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
        ### if ip is in list:
           ...
```

and then add the middleware path to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES

```
 MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
     ...,
     'path-to-middleware-MiddleWare2CheckIP',
     ...
 )
```

OR

You can have a decorator that you can use with all apis, to check if the request is from certain IPs

Comment: Thank you. I am trying with middleware to authenticate before a request is processed. But am struck at the point where I have to generate a token. Can I have a setup like whenever a new client machine registers itself a token to be generated? Without any users involved.

Comment: Please check django token based authentication. Use something like django-allauth.